# How to add styles in Ag-Grid FIlter Apply and Clear Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid to add table in my application.

Right now I am trying to add styles to ag-grid Filter buttons, like Apply, Clear.
[image]

I added these like in column definition to display the button

```
filterParams: {
        buttons: ['clear', 'apply'],
        closeOnApply: true,
      },
```

But, how can I change the styles of the Clear and Apply Button?

Comment: Examine the button elements and create your own CSS rules that override the current styles.

Comment: Both have the same class name and I want different styles for both

Comment: Use CSS pseudo-classes to target the first, last, etc of the same class.